# how capacitors and diodes hooked up as pictured?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, ac, diodes, dc

[image]

Will this set up act like a dc battery?  Can i have this in series with an ac voltage source?

Comment: 1) No. 2) Yes, but why?

Comment: Once the capacitors get charged up, the diodes will be permanently reverse-biased, blocking any further current flow. What would be the point?

Comment: Rather than asking a *weird* question, tell us what you plan to do with it and we might come up with a better solution to your *actual* problem.

Comment: Sorry I am a novice.  I am trying to stabilize the voltage in an ac circuit. Specifically   when two ac sources are connected in parallel  and one of the two goes to 0 volts. how to efficiently maintain an adequate voltage.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, @TammaraBrown: You need to edit your question and improve your question quite a bit. (1) What are your two AC sources? e.g. Transformers, audio signals, radio signals? What voltages and currents and frequencies? (2) What are you feeding them into? (3) What would cause one of them to go to 0 V?

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSRAjR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Full circuit. (b) Redrawn as the familiar dual-rail half-wave rectifier.*

- If you remove D2 and C2 it should be obvious that D1 and C1 form a half-wave rectifier. Since there is no discharge path C1 will charge up to the peak positive voltage of the AC supply and remain there.
- Adding in D2 and C2 again doesn't affect the voltage on C1.
- D2 and C2 form a negative half-cycle rectifier. C2 will charge negative and remain charged. No further current will flow.